# PHPExcel file does not exsit

Tags: phpexcel

Please kindliy help out.Am using php excel with laravel but whenever i try to import excel file into database i get error "Error loading file "update.xlsx": Could not open localhost:9090/xls/update.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.".

My xls folder is placed in my public directory and am loading phpexcel with composer.Kindly help out i ddont know what am doing wrong.thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION START HERE   ****************************/

define ("DB_HOST", "lhost"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "root"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS",""); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","name"); // set database name

// $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
// $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

$databasetable = "applicant";

$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION END HERE  ****************************/


set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');


// This is the file path to be uploaded.
 $inputFileName = asset("xls/".$filename);; 

try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}


$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet


for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
{
$surname    = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]));
$othernames = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]));
$address    = strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);
$lga        = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]));
$sex        = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]));
$dob        = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["F"]));
$genotype   = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]));
$blood_grp  = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["H"]));
$phone      = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["I"]));
$email      = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["J"]));
$occupation = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["K"]));
$place_emp  = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["L"]));
$facility   = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["M"]));
$medical_his = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["N"]));
$allergy    = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["O"]));
$reg_frm    = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["P"]));
$reg_to     = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["Q"]));
$collector  = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["R"]));
$form_no    = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["S"]));
$tell_no    = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["T"]));
$amt_paid   = trim(strtoupper($allDataInSheet[$i]["U"]));

$query = "SELECT surname FROM `applicant` WHERE `surname` = '$surname' and `othernames` = '$othernames'";
$sql = $con->query($query);
$recResult = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$existName = $recResult["surname"];
if($existName=="") {
$insertTable= $con->query("insert into `applicant` (surname, othernames,address,lga,sex,dob,genotype,blood_grp,phone,email,occupation,place_emp,facility,medical_his,allergy,reg_frm,reg_to,collector,form_no,tell_no,amt_paid) 
    values('".$surname."', '".$othernames."','".$address."','".$lga."','".$sex."','".$dob."',
        '".$genotype."','".$blood_grp."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$occupation."',
        '".$place_emp."','".$facility."','".$medical_his."','".$allergy."','".$reg_frm."',
        '".$reg_to."','".$collector."','".$form_no."','".$tell_no."','".$amt_paid."');");


$msg = 'Record has been added';
} 
else 
{
$msg = 'Record already exist';
}
}
echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>".$msg."</div>";


?>
```

Comment: please someone kindly help me out

Comment: This code has nothing in common with Laravel. I removed Laravel tag because this is not Laravel code style. You should rather use Laravel Excel http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs and read Laravel documentation how you should create Laravel applications

Comment: i delibrately did not use the laravel blade format for this because using the DB class or calling retrieving data using the model class wont be easily manipulated.and for the Laravel Excel:it doesn't show any documentation on how to import excel data into database

Comment: It's the same hard as using laravel DB connections. What you created here seems like framework profanation. It's plain PHP code mixed with HTML and it has nothing in common with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is "composer" and what the `asset()` function is supposed to be doing, but normally for file uploads to a PHP script you'd use a "mime/multipart" web form with a file input, and then the PHP runtime will consume the file and make it available in the `$_FILES` array. Read the [PHP manual on handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more information.

Comment: the file as already been uploaded,and the asset() function returns the part to the public directory.e.g asset('img') returns public/img.and the function you see i posted above is a PHPExcel function

Comment: It looks like `asset()` returns a URL and not a local path on the server, which is what `load()` expects. If the file is present on the server then find some other way to locate the file. I dont know what you used to store the uploaded file, and im nor familiar with Laravel, so i cant help you more, sorry

Comment: ok tanks.but the file was uploaded into a folder "xls" in my public directory with an upload form

Comment: Then you should be able to locate the file if you know the full path to your public directory. Try using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel cannot open a file from a URL, only from the local filesystem. As the url that you're using (`localhost`)suggests that file is on the server's filesystem, us a full filesystem path instead

Comment: please an example will help please

Comment: Instead of using `asset("xls/".$filename)`, use the real filesystem path (e.g. `/var/www/html/xls/' . $filename`) or whatever your web root directory is pointing to

Comment: Thanks this works "C:/xampp/htdocs/OYSG/public/xls/update.xlsx".When i push it to the server i will reset the file path.thanks again

Comment: With laravel, you should be able to use `$inputFileName = public_path() . '/xls/' . $filename;` which should work on every server